# Como hacer un tablero de 6 x 6 usando la libreria swing, en netbeans, y con que elementos es la mejor forma de realizarla?

Tags: java

tengo este proyecto para mi clase de programacion 1 para el cual debo realizar un juego de tablero, y pues no se como hacer el tablero, me gustaria que me ayudaran de que forma realizarlo usando el pallete, desde ya muchas gracias por contestarme.

Comment: Una mejor forma no existe, pero dentro de los materiales de tus clases deberías encontrar documentación sobre layouts. Te recomiendo `GridLayout'. Empieza con eso, y revisa el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre buenas formas de preguntar, por favor. En caso de estudios, comparte detalles de la tarea.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un **GridLayout** (Distribución en cuadricula), y en cada celda agrega un **JPanel** al cual le puedes poner un color de fondo y un borde si es que necesitas que se distingan unas celdas de otras.

Aqui un poco de codigo:

```
///Define el tamaño de la cuadricula. 

Nombre_De_Tu_Frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,6));

///for para agregar paneles.
for(int i=0;i<6*6;i++){
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.red);  ///se asigna un color.
Border borde;
borde = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);  ///se le pone un borde.
panel.setBorder(borde);
Nombre_De_Tu_Frame.add(panel); ///Se agrega el panel a la cuadricula una vez que tiene color y borde.
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda,me sirvio de mucho, fijate que ahora estoy trabado en otra parte de mi proyecto, quiero hacer que un objeto se mueva de un JPanel a otro JPanel en tiempo de ejecucion, como puedo lograr eso? usando el metodo remove?